# Rearrange data into multiple columns in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot, aggregation

I'm extracting timeseries data from an database, were data is stored per row, with a type field also stored. (i.e. the table has fields for Timestamp, Datatype, Value).

```
Timestamp   Type    Value
---------------------------
2019-07-22  Offset  0,7047
2019-07-22  Multi   0,9805
2019-07-22  Value   6,6526
2019-07-22  Output  1,1223
2019-07-23  Offset  0,7005
2019-07-23  Multi   0,9850
2019-07-23  Value   6,6955
2019-07-23  Output  1,1150
2019-07-24  Offset  0,6980
2019-07-24  Multi   0,9853
2019-07-24  Value   6,6996
2019-07-24  Output  1,1143
```

There is a fixed number of different Datatypes in the data, and I need the data structured with each Datatype as a column.

```
Timestamp   Offset  Multi   Value   Output
-------------------------------------------
2019-07-22  0,7047  0,9805  6,6526  1,1223
2019-07-23  0,7005  0,9850  6,6955  1,1150
2019-07-24  0,6980  0,9855  6,6995  1,1143
```

Is this possible to do within a SQL query?

The reason I want to do it within a query is that I'm running the query in an application interface, which then outputs the result in a table that can be copy-pasted into the tool without doing any rearranging manually. (That is, I'm not doing the query as part of a program, so I can't do it in any code outside of the SQL query)

Comment: GROUP BY timestamp, use case expressions for multi etc in the select list.

Answer (score 3):

If the no of columns are fixed, You can use CASE pivot method -

```
SELECT Timestamp
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  Type = 'Offset' THEN Value END) Offset
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  Type = 'Multi' THEN Value END) Multi
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  Type = 'Value' THEN Value END) Value
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  Type = 'Output' THEN Value END) Output
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY Timestamp;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Conditional Aggregation :

```
 select Timestamp, 
        max(case when Type = 'Offset' Then Value end) as Offset, 
        max(case when Type = 'Multi' Then Value end) as Multi,  
        max(case when Type = 'Value' Then Value end) as Value,
        max(case when Type = 'Output' Then Value end) as Output
   from tab
  group by Timestamp
  order by Timestamp;
```

Another option would be using a query with `pivot` keyword :

```
select *
  from
  (
    select * 
      from tab
  ) 
  pivot(
         max(value) for Type in ( 'Offset' as "Offset", 'Multi' as "Multi", 
                                  'Value' as "Value", 'Output' as "Output" )
       )
  order by Timestamp;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b69683fb7741afb5f0eab0dfb8ea4ec7)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamp column has fractional time component and you want to truncate it to seconds it would be like:

```
SELECT cast (systimestamp as date) ddate
  ,MAX(DECODE  (Type, 'Offset', Value)) Offset
  ,MAX(DECODE  (Type, 'Multi',  Value)) Multi
  ,MAX(DECODE  (Type, 'Value',  Value)) Value
  ,MAX(DECODE  (Type, 'Output', Value)) Output
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY cast (systimestamp as date);
```